# Oracle deleting rows from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i'm trying to delete rows from multiple tables but i'm getting a syntax error at medewerkers m,

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here? :

```html
declare
v_mnr medewerkers.mnr%type;
procedure ontsla_med(p_mnr in medewerkers.mnr%type)
IS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM medewerkers m, INSCHRIJVINGEN i , UITVOERINGEN u WHERE m.MNR = p_mnr and i.cursus = p_mnr and u.docent = p_mnr;
END ontsla_med;
BEGIN
    ontsla_med(7000);
END;
```

Seems like the delete statement is wrong?

Comment: One DELETE per table.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be trying to delete data from parent and child tables, in which case you might want to create foreign key constraints with the ON DELETE CASCADE option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't do it. It has to be three separate deletes.

```
DELETE 
  FROM medewerkers
 WHERE mnr = p_mnr;

DELETE 
  FROM UITVOERINGEN 
 WHERE cursus = p_mnr;

DELETE 
  FROM UITVOERINGEN 
 WHERE docent = p_mnr;
```

Comment: Thanks, thought it was possible to add multiple tables at once