# Delete Operation to delete data from multiple left outer join

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

```
DELETE mp.*, rp.*, per.*, pv.*
FROM my_privilege mp 
LEFT JOIN ro_priv rp ON rp.privilege_id IN (privilege_id_rep)
LEFT JOIN person_priv per ON per.person_priv_id IN (privilege_id_rep)
LEFT JOIN privilege pv ON pv.privilege_id IN (privilege_id_rep)
WHERE (logino_id = p_int_logino_id);
```

Above code is delete operation which is in mysql ,I need to convert same to oracle 12c database.
Could you please help me out

As Oracle will not support multiple deletes in a single query.

I need the approach of how to do delete operation when we have

```
delete from table
left join table1
left join table2
left join table3
left join table4
where condition
```

operations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525456/oracle-deleting-rows-from-multiple-tables

Comment: above answer is not useful for me.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, the "above answer", i.e. separate DELETE statements per table, gives the only valid Oracle syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, in Oracle you're supposed to delete table-by-table, i.e. you can't affect multiple tables in a single `DELETE` statement. Therefore, that would be

```
delete from my_privilege mp
  where mp.some_id in (select x.some_id from some_other_table x ...);

delete from person_priv per
  where per.some_id in (select x.some_id from some_other_table x ...);

etc.
```

If there are foreign key constraints, see whether `ON DELETE CASCADE` is used so that deleting a master row deletes all details (in a single statement).

Comment: Yes but here i have multiple left join

Comment: So then I need                                                                                                     
   delete from my_privilege mp
  where mp.some_id in (  HERE I NEED TO have all the left joins);